# Is it possible to do a group by count(distinct) without a join?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, distinct

```
Table 1 : (Company)

ID Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

Each company (pk = ID) can have one or more employees.

```
Table 2 :  (Employee)  (CompanyID referencing ID)

CompanyID EmpID Name
1         1     Joe
1         2     Doe
1         3     Boe
2         4     Lou
3         5     Su  
3         6     Ram
```

Query :

```
select CompanyID, count(*) from Employee group by CompanyID having count(*) > 1; # Lists companies and their counts.

CompanyID count(*)
1         3  
3         2
```

For this query, I want just one result with the count of distinct CompanyIDs. So, '2' in this case [Companies A and C].

In short, I am looking for number of companies with 2 or more employees.

Is there anyway to get the result without a temp table or a join? I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
select count(*) from
(select CompanyID from Employee group by CompanyID having count(*) > 1) v
```

or for ranges:

```
select count(*) from
(select CompanyID from Employee group by CompanyID 
 having count(*) >= 5 and count(*) < 10) v
```

Comment: I was contemplating on this solution but I thought this might not be the most efficient. May be it is! Thanks...

Comment: Can we do count(*) on ranges? Say, number of companies with 5 or more employees but less than 10?

Comment: Sorry, I got it : having count(*) >= 5 or count(*) < 10

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM Employee 
    GROUP BY CompanyID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) AS grp
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CompanyID) 
FROM Employee AS e
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Employee AS e2
        WHERE e2.CompanyID = e.CompanyId
          AND e2.EmpID <> e.EmpID
      )
```

or perhaps if `COUNT(*)` is slow, you can use `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( SELECT 1 
    FROM Employee 
    GROUP BY CompanyID 
    HAVING MAX(EmpID) > MIN(EmpId)
  ) AS grp
```

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias. So an alias is required I guess..

Comment: Yes, aliases are needed in subqueries.